# Pochhammer Simplification

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

Assumption:: m and n are integers and greater than zero.

```
$Assumptions = {Element[m, Integers] && m >= 0, Element[n, Integers] && n >= 0}
```

Consider the following,

```
Pochhammer[n + a_, m_] :>  Pochhammer[a, m + n]/Pochhammer[a, n]
```

This simplifies the Pochhammers with arguments (n+a+b,m).

```
in : Pochhammer[n + a + b, m]
out : Pochhammer[a + b, m + n]/Pochhammer[a + b, n]
```

I want to generalize it, so that it simlifies
`Pochhammer[3n + a + b, 2m]` to `Pochhammer[ a + b, 3n+2m]`

I tried as follows,

```
Pochhammer[n_Integers + a_, m_Integers] :>  Pochhammer[a, m + n]/Pochhammer[a, n]
```

or

```
Pochhammer[n*x_Integers + a_, m*y_Integers] :>  Pochhammer[a, y*m + x*n]/Pochhammer[a, x*n]
```

None of them works. Can anyone tell what is wrong here, what the correct way?

Comment: You cannot use `Integers` this way. The pattern `n_Integers` represents any expression (`Blank[]`), here called `n` **that has `Head` `Integers`**. But in Mathematica, `Integers` is not used as a `Head`, it's used as an assumption for `Solve`ing, `Simplify`ing etc.

Comment: In your case, the inputs you are matching will either have `Head` equal to `Symbol` for your undefined variables, or if you input numbers, they will have one of several `Head`s  used for numbers. In that case, the pattern should usually be `n_?IntegerQ` or `n_?NumericQ`.

Comment: @marius, there’s also the head [`Integer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integer.html) (notice the lack of “s”), so `n_Integer` would work as well. That is what `IntegerQ` looks for, according to the documentation.

Comment: At the beginning, I assume m and n are integers and greater than zero then tried these, `Pochhammer[a_ + n_Integer, m_] :> Pochhammer[a, m + n]/
 Pochhammer[a, n]` on `Pochhammer[a + n, m]`. This does not work

Comment: `Pochhammer[a_ + n_?IntegerQ, m_] :> Pochhammer[a, m + n]/
 Pochhammer[a, n]` does not help too.

Comment: bdw, after`$Assumptions = Element[n, Integers] && n >= 0` should not `Head[n]` give`Integer`? Its giving `Symbol`

Answer (score 1):

The answer that I was looking for is

```
sim = Pochhammer[ x_. (z_. n + a_), m___] :>  Pochhammer[  x a, m + x z n]/
 Pochhammer[x a, x z n]
```

It does the following simplifications

```
in:= Pochhammer[2 n + a, m] //. sim
out:=Pochhammer[a, m + 2 n]/Pochhammer[a, 2 n]
in:=Pochhammer[n + 3 a, m] //. sim
out:=Pochhammer[3 a, m + n]/Pochhammer[3 a, n]
in:=Pochhammer[-5 n + 3 a, m] //. sim
out:=Pochhammer[3 a, m - 5 n]/Pochhammer[3 a, -5 n]
in:=Pochhammer[-5 n + 3 a + 2 b - d, m] //. sim
out:=Pochhammer[3 a + 2 b - d, m - 5 n]/Pochhammer[3 a + 2 b - d, -5 n]
```

But,

```
in:=Pochhammer[-5 n + 3/2 (a - n) + 2 b - d/2, m] //. sim
out:=Pochhammer[2 b - d/2 + (3 (a - n))/2, m - 5 n]/Pochhammer[
 2 b - d/2 + (3 (a - n))/2, -5 n]
```

In order to avoid this problem,

```
in:=Together /@ Pochhammer[-5 n + 3/2 (a - n) + 2 b - d/2, m] //. sim
out:=Pochhammer[1/2 (3 a + 4 b - d), m - (13 n)/2]/Pochhammer[
 1/2 (3 a + 4 b - d), -((13 n)/2)]
```